# #cipherpuzzlesarecool

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher

The image tells you everything.

> 1.6.3.8.926.1.759 751 578. (8, 5)

[image: ``]

hint:

> borders

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **PORKCHOP STEAK**

> If you zoom the image, you will see PIGPEN typed above the numpad.
>  [image]

So,

> We know that its [PIGPEN Cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher). So, we have to use the grids to solve this. Now, the grid to be used is the same numpad grid shown in the picture. We arrange the alphabets in the same grid -
>  A B C
>  D E F
>  G H I
>  and
>  J K L
>  M N O
>  P Q R
>  Now, if we use the numbers, where first grid is a normal grid and second being dot grid, we get letters like -
>  1. - P
>  6. - O
>  3. - R
>  8. - K
>  9 -  C
>  2 -  H
>  6. - O
>  1. - P
>
>  **PORKCHOP** for first part..Now the 3 digit blocks of 759 looks like a V on Grid which could mean **S** and 751 looks like > which could mean **T** and remaining is **EAK** using the first two grids again.
>  Here's a visual of the grids we use -
>  Here are visual grids(4th is not used)....
>  [image]
>  [image]

So we get

> **PORKCHOP STEAK** which also fits the enumeration (8,5)